# Alter Master Page based on login type: ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, master-pages

Currently for work I am recreating a C# ASP application from an older ASP framework. My client wants a sidebar on every page for quick navigation. This was easy enough to do. There are 5 different user types for this application. Some are not allowed access to some of the links in the side bar. I have created a master page with every item in the sidebar visible and functional.

I need to know if there is a way to dynamically make some of the items in the master page's side bar no longer appear when a specific user is signed in.

Also, if it would be better to create the side bar as a dynamic data field .ascx file instead.

Comment: You could use a sitemap and filter using roles. There's a great article [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178429(v=vs.140).aspx) on how to do just that. How are you currently handling roles?

Comment: I tried that. 
That just prevents users from making it to certain websites, it doesn't actually get rid of the item on the bar.

From what I can tell I am stuck using a standard ascx file and writing out the table and if statements from scratch.